# How to find points of tangency on an ellipse?

Tags: calculus, geometry, conic-sections

The problem I have to solve is:
    If tangent lines to ellipse $9x^2+4y^2=36$ intersect the y-axis at point $(0,6)$, find the points of tangency.

Comment: You are missing some $y^2$ somewhere in your expression. Can you take a look at it again?

Comment: None of the ([multivariable-calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariable_calculus)), ([elliptic-curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve)) or ([elliptic-functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_function)) tags are representative of this question.

Answer (score 7):

Using implicit differentiation, you can find the slope of a line tangent to the ellipse at a point $(a,b)$ on the ellipse. Taking the derivative,
$$
18x+8y\frac{dy}{dx}=0\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-9x}{4y}.
$$
So the slope of a tangent line at a point $(a,b)$ is $\frac{-9a}{4b}$, so the equation of such is line is
$$
y-b=\frac{-9a}{4b}(x-a)
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
9ax+4by=9a^2+4b^2=36.
$$
Since this line must also pass through $(0,6)$, plugging in you find $24b=36$, or $b=3/2$. Substituting back into the original equation yields $a=\pm\sqrt{3}$, so the two points of tangency are $(\pm\sqrt{3},3/2)$.

Answer (score 3):

A standard way to solve the problem is to consider the generic line passing through $(0,6)$ which has equation
$$
y-6=mx,
$$
then make a substitution in the ellipse equation and impose that the resulting one variable quadratic equation has a double root. This will give you the values $m$ of the tangent lines.

Answer (score 3):

We use a linear transformation. Go from $(3x)^2+(2y)^2=6^2$ to $u^2+v^2=1$ by using a change of coordinates with $u=\frac{1}{2}x$ and $v=\frac{1}{3}y$. Tangencies and intersections are preserved, so there are two lines tangent to the unit circle intersecting the point $(0,2)$ in the $uv$-plane; they will be symmetric across the $v$-axis so finding one is enough. Make a right triangle with one vertex at the origin $O$, one at the point of tangency $T$ (say on the right side), and one at $P=(0,2)$, with $\phi=\angle POT$; then trigonometry dictates $\cos\phi=1/2\implies\phi=\pi/3$, hence the points in the $uv$-plane are
$$(\cos(\pi/2-\phi),\sin(\pi/2-\phi))=\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right),\text{ and}$$
$$(-\cos(\pi/2-\phi),\sin(\pi/2-\phi))=\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right).$$
Transform these points back into the $xy$-plane using $x=2u,y=3v$ and obtain
$(\pm\sqrt{3},3/2).$

Answer (score 2):

Yet another method: converting the equation of the ellipse into the form

$$\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}=1$$

and by exploiting the identity

$$\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)^2=1$$

we obtain the parametrization

$$\begin{align*}x&=2\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\\y&=\frac{6t}{1+t^2}\end{align*}$$

From this parametrization, we derive the equation of the tangent line:

$$y=\frac{3(t^2-1)}{4t} \left(x-2\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)+\frac{6t}{1+t^2}$$

or, simplified,

$$y=\frac{3(t^2-1)}{4t}x+\frac{3\left(t^2+1\right)}{2t}$$

We ask that the $y$-intercept of the tangent line be $6$; equating the constant term of the linear equation to $6$ and rearranging yields

$$3 t^2-12 t+3=0$$

which has the roots $t=2\pm\sqrt{3}$; substituting these values of $t$ into the original parametric equations yields the tangency points $\left(\pm\sqrt 3,\dfrac32\right)$.

Comment: Does that identity (that is being exploited) have a name?

Comment: I actually cheated a bit by implicitly using the Weierstrass substitution here, Chaz. :)

Comment: I was gonna say... if my students tried to exploit such an identity, well... they might need to teach me first!

Comment: I presented it anyway since the Weierstrass substitution is so useful for solving algebraic problems involving trigonometrics. Even when, no, especially when you're using Gröbner bases.

Comment: I see. Cheers!.

Answer (score 0):

First, use implicit differentiation to find the derivative of both sides.

$$9x^2 + 4y^2 = 36$$

$$18x + 8yy' = 0$$

$$8yy' = -18x$$

$$y' = \frac{-18x}{8y}$$

$$y' = \frac{-9x}{4y}$$

This shows that the slope of the tangent line is given by the equation:
$$y' = \frac{-9x}{4y}$$

Next, we need to find the slope of the tangent line more specifically at $(0,6)$, so we can plug that into $y'$ to get:

$$y'(0,6) = \frac{-9(0)}{4(6)}$$

$$y'(0,6) = 0$$

Thus, the slope of the tangent line at $(0,6)$ is 0. We also know that for any tangent line, the equation of the tangent line with a given point $(x_1, y_1)$ is:

$$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$$ where m = slope of the tangent line.

Given the point $(0,6)$, we can substitute $(0,6)$ for $(x_1, y_1)$ and substitute the slope $\frac{-9(0)}{4(6)}$ for m.

$$y-6= \frac{-9(0)}{4(6)}(x-0)$$
$$y-6=\frac{-9(x^2)}{4y}$$

From here, we can solve for $y$ by multiplying $4y$ on both sides.
$$4y(y-6)=-9x^2$$
$$4y^2-24y=-9x^2$$
$$(9x^2+4y^2)-24y=0$$
Now we have come to the expression $9x^2+4y^2$ in the equation, which is the original equation of the ellipse, equaling 36. So, we can substitute 36 into the equation:

$$36-24y=0$$
$$36=24y$$
$$y=\frac{36}{24}$$
$$y=\frac{3}{2}$$

Now, we can plug our value for $y$ into the original equation $9x^2+4y^2=36$:

$$9x^2+4(\frac{3}{2})^2=36$$
$$9x^2+4(\frac{9}{4})=36$$
$$9x^2+9=36$$
$$9x^2=27$$
$$x^2=3$$
$$\left\lvert x \right\rvert = \sqrt3$$
$$x=\pm\sqrt3$$

Therefore, the points of tangency are:
$$(-\sqrt3,\frac{3}{2}),(\sqrt3, \frac{3}{2})$$